# Laravel intervention/image doesn't resize image

Tags: laravel, resize, intervention

I am trying to use laravel intervention plugin. I installed it without problem but can't use it. 
I am trying to make a test function which returns resized image, but without success;
I think the problem may be in image path, please help me fix my code.

```js
function test($img)
{
   /* $img = Image::make('public/image1.jpg');
    $img->resize(300, 200);
    return $img; */

   $image = Image::make('http://localhost/cms/digital-cms/public/image1.jpg')->resize(200, 200, function ($c) {
        $c->aspectRatio();
        $c->upsize();
    });
    return $image;

    //$h=200; $w=200;
    //return Image::make(public_path('public/image1.jpg')->resize($h, $w)->response('jpg'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 //get image
 $image=$request->file('image');
 //rename image
 $input = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //your directory to upload
            $destinationPath = 'main/images/company';
            //save and resize image
            $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
            $img->resize(20,20, function ($constraint) {
              $constraint->aspectRatio();
              })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use response function on `Image` class to return the image

```
$image = Image::make('http://localhost/cms/digital-cms/public/image1.jpg')->resize(200, 200, function ($c) {
    $c->aspectRatio();
    $c->upsize();
});
return $image->response();
```

Comment: thank you ver much for your time and help.
I changed it but the result is the same.
if I write dd($image->response());
it displays something.. 
see image here. 
http://imgur.com/a/LJA8s

Comment: this is the laravel response object. sent me a image of the actual response

Comment: it returns empty.

Comment: Probably the problem is with url of the image. try getting the image locally and not from url. `base_url().'/public/image1.jpg'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was resizing, cropping (fit) but the final image is still the same as original. Found out that I had to add function encode, to produce the manipulated image

```php
return $image->encode('jpg', 80);
```